# C Executable does not run on linux Mint

Tags: c, linux, executable, linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca xfce edition.
I installed libc6-dev and successfully compiled a C program.
My .out does not execute when I double click the file, nor when I right click and select execute. I have actually looked for an answer to this but all answers I found were so specific that it did not answer my question. 
Also I have recently migrated from Windows. Just want you to know I am not quite Linux Savvy. I am also new to programming.

Comment: Is this a console program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much information on the nature of the program itself. So I'm going to assume it is a console program. On Windows, running a console program from say, a file manager will cause a console window to appear. However, on Linux this will cause the program to run 'in the background' (ie. it will not create a console window). The answer is to run the program through a terminal.

```
$ cd /directory/of/executable
$ ./executable_name
```

Comment: This worked just fine. I'm actually doing a self study of C Primer Plus 6th Edition. Thanks a lot this will let me continue my study now.

Comment: What if it's a graphical program that uses a console behind it for debug logging? Is it possible to make it force foreground running?